# Python Import gives packge not found even after __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-import, importerror

```
Test
|   
|   __init__.py
|   
\---Mypackage
    |   qqq.py
    |   __init__.py
    |   
    +---effects
    |       abc.py
    |       
    \---Sound
        |   __init__.py
        |   
        \---formats
                xyz.py
```

When I try to import in xyz.py “from Mypackage.effects import abc”

I get,

```
C:\Test>python C:\Test\Mypackage\Sound\formats\xyz.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Test\Mypackage\Sound\formats\xyz.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Mypackage.effects import abc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Mypackage'
```

Comment: You've tagged your question with both [tag:Python-3.x] and [tag:Python-2.7], but you're probably only using one of those versions. Can you please remove the irrelevant tag? Or heck, since this problem is mostly version independent, you could remove them both. Regarding the question, how are you running `xyz.py`? Are you calling `python xyz.py` from the `formats` folder? Have you tried `python -m Mypackage.Sound.formats.xyz` from within the `Test` folder?

Comment: i was trying to get abc  imported to xyz file. It did not succeed. But when i give C:\Test>python -m Mypackage.Sound.formats.xyz it did not complain Also C:\Test>python -m Mypackage.effects.abc also worked with out issue. But when the import is part of the xyz.py file it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to add the following lines in xyz.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path_to_your_Test_folder')
from Mypackage.effects import abc
```

and then run this script like the way you showed in your question.

**Note: Above solution is tested using python3.5 and ubuntu 16.04**